# Trying to dump information to a json, but getting double backslashs

Tags: json, python-3.x, encoding

I have some info store in a MySQL database, something like: `AHmmgZq\n/+AH+G4`

We get that using an API, so when I read it in my python I get: `AHmmgZq\\n/+AH+G4` The backslash is doubled!

Now I need to put that into a JSON file, how can I remove the extra backslash?

**EDIT:** let me show my full code:

```
json_dict = {
    "private_key": "AHmmgZq\\n/+AH+G4"
}

print(json_dict)
print(json_dict['private_key'])

with open(file_name, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    json.dump(json_dict, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
```

In the first print I have the doubled backslash, but in the second one there's only one. When I dump it to the json file it gives me doubled.

Comment: When you print a dictionary you get its __repr__. When you print the inner key you get its __str__ representation. In the repr, python shows the backslash used to escape, but in the string it just applies the escape. You are using that private key to send a request to an api? Try reading the key from the generated json and making the request. Everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved my problem was this:

```
string_to_json.replace("\\n","\n")
```

Thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 0):

`"AHmmgZq\\n/+AH+G4"` in python is equivalent to the literal string `"AHmmgZq\n/+AH+G4".` `print("AHmmgZq\\n/+AH+G4") => "AHmmgZq\n/+AH+G4"`

`\n` is a new line character in python. So to represent `\n` literally it needs to be escaped with a `\`. I would first try to convert to json as is and see if that works.

Otherwise for removing extra backslashs:

```
string_to_json.replace("\\\\","\\")
```

Remember that `\\` = escaped \ = \

But in the above string that will not help you, because python reads `"AHmmgZq\\n/+AH+G4"` as `"AHmmgZq\n/+AH+G4"` and so finds no double backslash.

Comment: Yes, I've realized that, and tried the replace, but it didn't work. In your code you have a replace.replace, was that an error?

Comment: Apologies - fixed the double replace. Can you explain what you want the json to look like? And what your current output is giving you?

Comment: I want my json to look like: "AHmmgZq\n/+AH+G4", but now it has the double backslash

Comment: In Javascript \ also needs to be escaped. That's why you are seeing a double backslash. That is how the string should be formatted. You shouldn't need to do anything

Comment: I have added new information in the question, I think you'll see it clearer now